# How to make a JTextArea scrollable in java?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Hi I have made a JTextArea but it is not scrolling, can someone please tell me why?

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(2, 0);
textArea.setText("sdsdsd \n dfdfdf \n dsdsdsdsd \n dsdsdsd \n sdsdsdsd");
textArea.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
panel.add(textArea);
```

Also, I would like it to auto scroll down, when new content gets added to, show it only shows the last 2 lines automatically, if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use,

```
panel.add(scrollPane);
```

not

```
panel.add(textArea);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the JScrollPane to the JPanel, not the JTextArea.

To Scroll to the bottom, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6243135/522444).