# Restricting a JFileChooser to a certain directory

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I need to restrict my `JFileChooser` to a directory and its children, because the file should only be saved on external media. I won't run into any problems with the external memory not being present, that has already been handled.

Should I...

- Override `getCurrentDirectory()`?
- Use a `FileFilter`? Normally these use `String.endsWith()`, but I would get the absolute path and restrict based on the path to the external device.

Comment: The first one probably won't do what you want, and if the second will it will confuse users. (Since most everything will be disabled without a clear explanation why.) I'd just default to external media, and display a warning / error if the user picks a location outside of one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restrict JFileChooser to a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529/how-do-i-restrict-jfilechooser-to-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely avoid implementing such restrictions. Its almost impossible to get this right (how can you determine *reliably* what is external storage?). It goes against user expectations.

A better approach would be to let the user pick any directory he likes, and when you detect the directory is probably unsuitable, display a *Warning* detailing why it is unsuitable. Offer two choices on the warning, like "Understood, proceed anyway" and "Pick another directory". And possibly an option to turn the warning off somewhere in the program options.