# JFileChooser: listing only files which start with a certain text string

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I would like to show with JFileChooser a list of all the files in a given folder, but ONLY those which start with a certain string, independently of they ending extension. This is because I have a folder with files which have the same name for 3-4 different extension, let's say i.e.: <<"customers.xls, customers.doc, customers.pdf, sales.xls, sales.txt, sales.doc...>>
The program will get a certain file name from an input/user, and I will like to get shown all the files which matched the given name.
As far as I managed untill now, is to find how to filter only on extensions, which does not manage what I need... Any hint on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330285/how-to-make-jfilechooser-display-only-a-folder-that-has-some-specific-name-java?rq=1). This is a solution which works with directories, but you can adapt the used File Filter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom FileFilter for it:

```
JFileChooser jfc = ...;
String filePrefix = "customers";
FileFilter ff = new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        return f.getName().startsWith(filePrefix);
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return "Custom Files";
    }
}

jfc.setFileFilter(ff);
```

Comment: Compact and simple... thankyou very much!

Comment: @PaulEfford It would be nice, when you accept an answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileFilter :

Definition:

```
class MyFilter implements FileFilter {

    String prefix;

    void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return "MyFiles";
    }

    public boolean accept(File f) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return f.getName().startsWith(prefix);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyFilter myFilter = new MyFilter();
myFilter.setPrefix("customer");

JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(myFilter);
```