# JChooser : Restricting view and add to a particular directory tree

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

This is a question that has been asked before, but there is a bug in that solution. 

My requirements are - when user invokes JFileChooser, he should not be able to navigate up the tree.

The answer has been to write a custom FileSystemView -
[How do I restrict JFileChooser to a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529/how-do-i-restrict-jfilechooser-to-a-directory)
Has a solution, as does 
http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/single-root-file-chooser/

However, both of them have a problem sometimes. For the correct implementation, the FileChooser should come up as -

[image]

However, sometimes, it appears as -
[image]

and user has to click the up arrow to see the correct directory. Any idea why this is happening please? And a solution ?

The code for the custom FileSystemView is

```
    public class SingleRootFileSystemView extends FileSystemView
{
    File root;
    File[] roots = new File[1];

    public SingleRootFileSystemView(File root)
    {
        super();
        this.root = root;
        roots[0] = root;
    }

    @Override
    public File createNewFolder(File containingDir)
    {
        File folder = new File(containingDir, "New Folder");
        folder.mkdir();
        return folder;
    }

    @Override
    public File getDefaultDirectory()
    {
        return root;

    }

    @Override
    public File getHomeDirectory()
    {
        return root;

    }

    @Override
    public File[] getRoots()
    {
        return roots;
    }
    }
```

The code to invoke this is

```
FileSystemView fsv = new SingleRootFileSystemView(folder);
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(fsv.getHomeDirectory(),fsv);
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(1);
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing us exactly what you're doing? What are you setting as the default file when you show it?

Comment: I ran your code and I never got what you "sometimes" got. Are you doing something special for the messed up file chooser to appear?