# How can i get all the list of directories and files in a drive in java. (All files in C:\)

Tags: java

I am writing a GUI program with java FX. The user can choose any directory in system. Unfortunately, directory chooser let the user choose a drive too.
We can list out all files and folders in a directory using file.listFiles(). What happens if a user choose a drive. The listfiles() is failing there with null pointer exception.

Is there any way i can get the list of files and directories in a drive in java?

```
    //Get files from the user computer
    public void getFileNames(File folder) {
        for (final File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                getFileNames(file);
            } else {
                if (FilenameUtils.isExtension(file.getName().toLowerCase(), videoFormatSet)) {
                    //Don't consider video files less than 100 MB
                    final Long FileSizeInMB = file.length() / 1048576;
                    if (FileSizeInMB < 100) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    final String fileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
                    if (!movieNameFilter(fileName).isEmpty()) {
                        movieFileNameList.add(movieNameFilter(fileName));
                    } else {
                        movieFileNameList.add(fileName);
                    }
                }
```

Edit:

The code lets a user chooses a directory (folder variable). The getFileNames() extract all the movie file Name in the chosen directory. The code is working fine when the user is selecting a directory.

But,JavaFx lets the user select a drive as well (i am using directory  chooser). Lets say for example, he chooses c drive (c:) in the system.

The value of file folder = E:\

The null pointer exception is happening when i am doing **folder.listFiles()** in 171st line

```
    171: for (final File file : folder.listFiles()) {
```

I can avoid this by adding a validation for not letting user chose a drive.

But if i want to let him choose a drive. Is there any way i can get list of all files in that drive?

Simply put, is it possible to write a code which lets user provide a drive (Ex: C or D) so that it can display all files in that drive.

**Stack Trace:**

Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.imdbrater.application.JavaFXApplication$GetfilesThread.getFileNames(JavaFXApplication.java:171)
    at com.imdbrater.application.JavaFXApplication$GetfilesThread.getFileNames(JavaFXApplication.java:173)
    at com.imdbrater.application.JavaFXApplication$GetfilesThread.getFileNames(JavaFXApplication.java:173)
    at com.imdbrater.application.JavaFXApplication$GetfilesThread.run(JavaFXApplication.java:167)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Did you try debugging it to see exactly where it gets the NPE?

Comment: Can we see the stack trace? Which line is throwing the NPE?

Comment: your code throws a NPE every time the program doesn't have sufficient rights to perform a directory listing.

Comment: Since you're using JavaFX, I assume you're using Java 7 or later.  Which means you should not be using the java.io.File class at all, as its reporting of errors is poor.  Use [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) instead.  To recursively list files, use one of the `walkFileTree` methods of Files (or `walk` if you're using Java 8).

Comment: Added the exact reason for NPE. @VGR: yes. I am using java 8. Thanks for the suggestion.Yes it makes more sense to use walkfileTree.

Comment: Loading every file seems like a rather bad thing to do. Have you tried [setting a FileSystemView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529/how-do-i-restrict-jfilechooser-to-a-directory)? I'd imagine they incorporated this to JFX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you performed some calls to different `movieNameFilter()` method, that was not declared in the piece of code you posted. Please make sure that this method is returning a correct value, as you call some methods on the returning objects.

You didn't post where the NullPointerException is happening, so I will base my answer on a simple and possible `null` output on the operation you are trying to perform.
Please be sure that the drive input by the user actually exists. 
As can be seen in [the API documentation for `java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29),

> **Returns:**
>
> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.**

In this case, if your user inputs a path that does not exist, you will get an NPE.

The best approach to handle this would be to firstly validate the user input. A secondary step involves validating the output of your `listFiles()` call.

```
// Get files from the user computer
public void getFileNames(File folder) {

    // retrieve file listing
    File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();

    if (fileList == null) {
        // throw an exception, return or do any other error handling here
        return;
    }

    // path is correct
    for (final File file : fileList ) {
        // etc etc etc
    }
}
```

If the NPE is related to any other error, please comment so I may update my answer accordingly.

---

**Note:** Please remember that filepaths in Java are escaped with double backslashes, so you should make your call in a way such as follows.

```
File rootFolder = new File("C:\\");
getFileNames(rootFolder);

File downloadsFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Downloads");
getFileNames(downloadsFolder);
```

Comment: The movieFilter function is just for cleaning the movieFile names.That function is not causing the NPE.The NPE is happening while doing listFiles() for a drive. File rootFolder = new File("C:\\");
getFileNames(rootFolder); will result in NPE. Is there any way to list out files in a drive?

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for detailing. Didn't my solution work? Or you didn't test it? =(

Comment: No.Unfortunately.It didn't work..Its still throwing NPE when trying listFiles() on the file.

Comment: Ok. Could you debug the code to see in which line the NPE occurs?