# Restrict JavaFX FileChooser to initial folder

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, filechooser

I want to **restrict** JavaFX File chooser to its initial directory.
I've seen that it's possible in Swing ([How do I restrict JFileChooser to a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529/how-do-i-restrict-jfilechooser-to-a-directory)) but I could not find anything similar in java fx.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Since it is a native window, I am not sure if that is even possible. Unless the javafx's FileChooser has a simular implementation as the JFileChooser.(which I haven't seen)

Comment: If you must have this feature, why not just use JFileChooser?

Answer (score 1):

This probably is a environment based window, and until java Specifies a Class for that (Which I feel it does not), you really can't do anything about it.

**But you could always let the user choose the directory and then check the directory and if it does not match your criteria, you could set the value to null and ask the user to input it again**

```
File f = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
if(f.getAbsolutePath().matches("regex")){
     //Do Something
}
```

Here regex would be replaced with somethinglike this

```
[.+]//yourPath
```

If you want to know more about regex, Visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: That is what I have done but I just don't like this solution. Thanks for trying to help anyhow